# Can I change the default variable delimiter in Freemarker?

Tags: java, perl, freemarker

I am working on a project where I am generating some code/scripts (specifically Perl scripts) via Java and Freemarker. I have it working for now, but was wondering if there was some way to change the default variable delimiter ($) in Freemarker?

Or is there a different Java template engine that would use a variable delimiter more suitable for generating a Perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would assume such a feature would reside in the same place as the ability to choose between angle bracket syntax and square bracket syntax.

http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html

I can't see anything about changing the interpolation syntax.

So I strongly belive that: no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The variable delimiter is not $foo, it is ${foo}.

I don't know perl, but to generate something with $ you do :

```
$${foo} -> $FOO

<#noparse>${</#noparse>${foo}} -> ${FOO}
```

Very cool :-)

I think best way is to make macro to put perl things in your interpolations, like [escape/noescape](http://www.freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html) directive.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for. I want to use a completely different delimiter than "$" for Freemarker. Not sure it's possible. What you have there is true and nice, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: OK. If you decid to go on with freemarker, post your question on user mailing list. This list is very reactive and the persons are very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar for the template language [FTL.jj](https://github.com/freemarker/freemarker/blob/master/src/main/javacc/FTL.jj#L640) hard-codes the `${` and `}` for a variable (an `FM_EXPRESSION`) being interpolated, so your best option may be to pre-process the file as suggested above.

Using `%{x}` as the FTL interpolation and leaving `${x}` untouched, this Perl one-liner would work:

```
% perl -spi.bak -e "s/\\$/\<#noparse\>\\$\<\/#noparse\>/g,s/\%\{/\\$\{/g" file
```

Before:

```
%{var}=${value}
```

After:

```
${var}=<#noparse>$</#noparse>{value}
```